# Compress String data suggestions for Audio Transfer on Delphi XE7

Tags: string, delphi, stream, compression

I am working for Audio Streaming on Delphi, capture and converting stream to string and send remote computers but how can i make better and fast than this?

```
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Text: String;
  sCompress: string;
begin
  try
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    Stream.WriteBuffer(Data^, len); //data = microphone capture
    Stream.Position := 0;
    SetLength(Text, Stream.Size);
    Stream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(Text)^, Stream.Size);
  finally
    Stream.Free;
    SendData(currentUser, Text);
  end;
```

Send Data basic winsock socket transfer, and i am writing receive data like this

```
WaveOut.waveOutDevice.write(Pointer(sBuf), Length(sBuf)); //sbuf = receivetext
```

This working but maybe will be better for your suggestions for data compressing. I think will be problem as the distance increases.

Comment: Don't use a string, use a byte array.

Comment: You don't need intermediate stream to put data in text - just use SetString. For compression - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.ZLib.TZCompressionStream

Comment: I agree with LU RD, there is no reason to use a string at all, especially since doing so will risk corrupting the audio data depending on how the string is handled. Binary data needs to be sent as-is, so it should be sent as a byte array or a stream, but definitely not as a string.

Comment: @LURD thanks for suggestions i am converting to bytearray now.

Comment: @MBo thanks for compression method

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you Remy, btw should i compress byte before send? is this risky for audio data?

Comment: @JamesFranklin compression is loss-less, it is safe to use, it just reduces bandwidth usage at the cost of requiring extra CPU overhead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for answer.

Comment: The stream and the string are superfluous. You already have raw binary data, send that directly to avoid needless allocation and copying. The try/finally is broken in two ways. Firstly the resource acquisition must be placed before the try. Otherwise you end up releasing a resource that was never acquired. Secondly, you send the message even if you fail to prepare it correctly. As for compression, there are many potential algorithms that you might use. Some lossless, some not. Which to select depends very much on what the audio is and how it is to be used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for explain David, you're right, i'll change my codes and i'll send direct raw data after compress.